# Trigger function from template to controller

Tags: php, frameworks, url-routing

I am using a mvc framework and I am stuck on a part.

In my frontcontroller, I have the following code:

```
class FrontController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $view_vars = array(
            'page_title' => 'Home',
            'page' => 'home'
        );

        $this->render("default_layout", $view_vars);
     }

     public function create(){
        $view_vars = array(
            'page_title' => 'Create Your Own MyChoice Package',
            'page' => 'home'
        );

        $this->render("default_layout", $view_vars);
     }
```

}

Futher to this I have a php file in my views folder as follows:

```
.....
<img class="imageCreate" src ="<?php print $theme_url; ?>images/create.jpg" />
<a href="create"><img class="BtnCreate" src="<?php print $theme_url; ?>images/vvv"/> </a>
<a href="predefined-package"> <img class="BtnChoose" src="<?php print $theme_url; ?>
......
```

The problem is I have created the function "create" in my controller but when triggering it, it is returning not found.

Even when I do

```
http://LOCATION/index
```

it returns not found.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your Router?

Comment: What Framework are you using? Looks like Yii?

Comment: Thanks all, I managed. The path need to be "?create".

@luttkens It is not Yii but rather another one build by bits from online tutorials.